# Jquery Json response works on everything but Ipad

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, ipad, jquery

I am posting back to get a list of stores after the user enters an address and clicks a button. This works great in all browsers except for the Ipad. In its case it returns a success status but an empty data object. Below is my script and server response code. I have googled everything I can think of but have not found a similar issue. Any help would be appreciated.

---Javascript---------------------

```
$.post("/storefinder/GetStores",
{
lng: lng,
lat: lat
},
function (data, status) {
var storeLoc = data.split(' -- ')
setupStores(storeLoc);
});
```

---MVC Controller code----------------

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetStores(string lng, string lat)
{
double dLng = double.MaxValue;
double dLat = double.MaxValue;
double.TryParse(lng, out dLng);
double.TryParse(lat, out dLat);
StringBuilder rtrnString = new StringBuilder();           

List<Hls.Mapping.Retailer> AllRetailers = Infrastructure.Cache.HeelysCacheItems.RetailerList(false);
List<Hls.Mapping.Retailer> ClosestRetailers = Hls.Mapping.MapRequest.ClosestRetailers(dLat, dLng, 20, AllRetailers);

foreach (Hls.Mapping.Retailer r in ClosestRetailers)
{
    rtrnString.Append(r.DisplayName);
    rtrnString.Append(" -- ");
    rtrnString.Append(r.Address1);
    rtrnString.Append(" -- ");
    rtrnString.Append(r.City + ", " + r.State + " " + r.ZipCode);
    rtrnString.Append(" -- ");
    rtrnString.Append(r.Phone);
    rtrnString.Append(" -- ");
    rtrnString.Append("Distance: " + Math.Round(r.distance, 2).ToString() + " miles");
    rtrnString.Append(" -- ");
    rtrnString.Append(r.Latitude.ToString());
    rtrnString.Append(" -- ");
    rtrnString.Append(r.Longitude.ToString());
    rtrnString.Append(" -- ");
}

return Json(rtrnString.ToString());
}
```

Comment: I figured out my issue it was in the button click javascript function. I was calling the jquery post before the geocode function was complete. I put the json call inside the results function of the geocode and it now works perfectly on all devices.